# debian lintian warns about non existing conffile

Tags: debian, lintian

I get a warning and one error from lintian:

```
W: openrobertalab: init.d-script-not-marked-as-conffile etc/init.d/openrobertalab
E: openrobertalab: init.d-script-not-included-in-package etc/init.d/openrobertalab
```

What I don't understand here is there is not such file `etc/init.d/openrobertalab` in my package:

```
dpkg --contents openrobertalab_1.3.0-1_amd64.deb | grep etc
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2015-09-22 10:53 ./etc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2015-09-22 10:53 ./etc/dbus-1/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2015-09-22 10:53 ./etc/dbus-1/system.d/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       489 2015-09-22 10:53 ./etc/dbus-1/system.d/openrobertalab.conf
```

If I follow lintiants advice and create a `debian/openrobertalab.conffiles` listing this non existing file, the package build fails:

```
dpkg-deb: error: conffile `etc/init.d/openrobertalab' does not appear in package
dh_builddeb: dpkg-deb --build debian/openrobertalab .. returned exit code 2
make: *** [binary] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing it exists in the `etc` directory of the build, but not sure which precise path and during which phase of the build process.  I'm guessing you will need to augment `debian/rules` to actually include it in the package.

Comment: I searched the temp dir of the package, there is no etc/init.d at all :/

Comment: for a proper anaylisis of the problem we would need to see more of your code; e.g. the contents of `debian/` (or a link to the packaging repo)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to 'fix' this by adding the lines below to my rules file:

```
override_dh_installinit:
# don't do anything, silences lintian warnings
```

Comment: instead you migth want to find out why `dh_installinit` wants to install the scripts in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, contact the documentation what the actual lintian errors mean:

```
 lintian-info --tags \
       init.d-script-not-included-in-package \
       init.d-script-not-marked-as-conffile
```

The explanation for the first warning suggests, that the `postinst` script for your package installs an init-script, but it is not part of the package.

So the proper solution would be fix the maintainer scripts of your package.

Comment: Sure, when I search for the error I get to pages like these: https://lintian.debian.org/tags/init.d-script-not-included-in-package.html and those are super unhelpful. I have not found any thing helpful on the checks in the lintian docs (https://lintian.debian.org/manual/index.html) either.

Thanks for pointing out 'lintian-info --tags', its beyond me why the tool is not including this in the output :/

Comment: But to comment on your conclusion, my postinst script does not install anything (https://gist.github.com/ensonic/14f5f3d2bceb90de5e07)

Comment: assuming that's the manually maintained debian/postinst script, how does the actual postinst script look like (after dh added stuff to it)?

Comment: where would I find that?

Comment: in the generated .deb file: e.g. `ar xvf yourpackage.deb && tar xvf control.tar.gz && cat postinst`

Comment: manual part here: https://github.com/OpenRoberta/robertalab-ev3dev/blob/develop/debian/openrobertalab.postinst